# Rewrite internally to a subdirectory and redirect old urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My website root folder is under a subfolder /web/ and all urls used to contains /web/toto.php. I changed this by putting a rules so that all requests point internally to the subfolder but the url is now shorter /toto.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

Now, the old adresses are still available and I need that the /web/* urls REDIRECTED to the short version. How to make this ? The file existence prevent me to write a rule that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a new redirect rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to externally redirect /web/path to /path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+web/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# to route /path to /web/path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: 302 is good for testing. Change it to 301 as it is working for you now.

Comment: I put this code in production but it doesn't work whereas it was in dev. I checked and found I have a .htaccess in the /web/ subfolder to append other specific sub-rules. I cleaned it and just keep one line "RewriteEngine On" but this line makes #1 rule (remove the /web in the url) doesn't work anymore but others rules are working. Any idea why just this one is not working ? I could merge the .htaccess but I'd like to understand the issue and let other people knows about.

Comment: If you have `/web/.htaccess` then you need to move rule #1 there.

Comment: It's working by moving the #1 to /web/.htaccess. Thanks